# Print only lines in html with '<a href> within a divider (HTML), using the BeautifulSoup stack

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to open a URL, find the divider labeled 'audience-container' and then ONLY print the lines that start with "a href". I have the first two parts done (I think) but can't figure out how to extract only the 'a href' lines from the section:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("httm://www.champlain.edu/current-students")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html parser")
for link in bs.find('div', {'id': 'audience-container'}):
    print(link) #this prints the full section under audience-container, but not what I want
    # print statement to pull out ONLY'a href' that I keep messing up
```

Comment: First of all you've got a typo. It's `http`(s), not `httm`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


main_url = "https://www.champlain.edu"
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"{main_url}/current-students").text, "html.parser")
for link in bs.find('div', {"id": "audience-nav"}).find_all("a"):
    print(f"{main_url}/{link.get('href')}")
```

Output:

```
https://www.champlain.edu/admitted-students
https://www.champlain.edu/current-students
https://www.champlain.edu/prospective-students
https://www.champlain.edu/undergrad-applicants
https://www.champlain.edu/online
https://www.champlain.edu/alumni
https://www.champlain.edu/parents
https://www.champlain.edu/faculty-and-staff
https://www.champlain.edu/school-counselors
https://www.champlain.edu/employer-resources
https://www.champlain.edu/prospective-employees
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.champlain.edu/current-students"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

In your code there's an error: httm insted of http.
I hope it's useful!

Comment: Thank you and to others. Feedback was very helpful.